# difference between logical and physical I/O?

Tags: c, linux, io, operating-system

I can't understand the difference between logical and physical I/O.
Can you explain the difference between them?

thanks

Comment: Some context would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms logical, physical, and virtual I/O are normally applied to disks. However, there can be application to other types of devices.

In the disk context, logical I/O treats a disk as a sequence of blocks, numbered 0 to N.

Physical I/O requires addressing disk blocks by platter, track, sector, block.

In the past operating systems implemented the physical to logical translation. Newer disks tend to implement logical I/O in the hardware (and automatically handle bad blocks).

Comment: "Physical" block numbering is a historical artifact of the ATA protocol. Hard drive controllers are more than capable of doing that level of math.

Comment: Physical I/O went way back before the ATA existed. The RA series disks were the first that I worked with that did the logical conversion the controller. The RP series the preceded it required physical I/O at the driver level (if memory holds).

Comment: Reference to ATA was only intended for intelligibility to a Linux audience. I don't think the question is referring to history.

Comment: this explanation is for logical block vs physical block thats not related to IO.

Answer (score 3):

there is a big difference between them,

Logical IO:
FS system calls resolved by FileSystem, that means they never reach the physical block device, for example you read a file and its content is in Page cache and buffer cache (all the necessary information is in cache Inode + blocks)
Your app will get the content given by the VFS+FS

Another example could be when you execute ls, first time the VFS needs to get all the inode information from the physical block device, second time the informaiton will be cached in dentry cache and wont be necessary to deeper to the physical device.

Physical:
For example a synchornic write, it will reach the Physical block device, if the write is async the blocks will be written in OS buffer (logical write)  and later all the dirty pages will be written together in the block device (physical) to improve the performance.

That is the reason it is very important to check how our FS is performing the IO to avoid physical IO. depending on the FS and the kernel parameters you can improve the caching to make it fit in what you need.

Comment: Very clear answer. i/o from file system perspective.